# Gfortran complex actual to real dummy argument

Tags: fortran, fft, gfortran, complex-numbers, real-datatype

I am trying to use fftpack with gfortran, but I am getting errors that i think relate to that some routines are passed complex arrays when the dummy argument is declared as real.

I read a comment on an intel fortran page that one could disable "**check routine interface**". Does anyone know if there is a similar option for gfortran?

I would like to not have to edit the fftpack... ( i guess this is because complex in memory is represented by two reals and the array arguments are passed as references but please correct me if I am wrong :) )

[to elaborate and meet the comments...]
So after downloading the dfftpack from netlib and compiling as a standalone file (f77 I pressume) with all subroutines in the same file I get a warning for example in

```
   SUBROUTINE DFFTF (N,R,WSAVE)
   IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
   DIMENSION       R(1)       ,WSAVE(1)
   IF (N .EQ. 1) RETURN
   CALL RFFTF1 (N,R,WSAVE,WSAVE(N+1),WSAVE(2*N+1))
   RETURN
   END
```

the waring appears when calling `CALL RFFTF1 (N,R,WSAVE,WSAVE(N+1),WSAVE(2*N+1))`. The beginning of RFFTF1 looks like this...

```
SUBROUTINE RFFTF1 (N,C,CH,WA,IFAC)
IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
DIMENSION       CH(*)      ,C(*)       ,WA(*)      ,IFAC(*)
```

and the warning from compiling hits the actual argument `WSAVE(2*N+1)` - to the dummy argument `IFAC`: (output from code::blocks build log window)

```
 mingw32-gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\  -Wall -g     -c
 C:\... \dfftpack.f -o obj\Debug\dfftpack.o
 C:\... \dfftpack.f:345.40:
 CALL RFFTB1 (N,R,WSAVE,WSAVE(N+1),WSAVE(2*N+1))                   
                                   1 Warning: Type mismatch in argument 
'ifac' at (1); passed REAL(8) to INTEGER(4)
```

I assume this will cause an incorrect result.. (the passing of a real to integer seems not to convert/round to the nearest integer but to something else. Does anyone know if it should be rounded in the call, like: `NINT(WSAVE(2*N+1))`?

Comment: If the routine has a real array dummy argument then putting a complex array actual argument and telling the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing" seems _interesting_.  Perhaps you just mean to pass the real component of the complex?

Comment: As far as I understand from Steve Lionels comment here https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/289586 it seems to be quite common....

Comment: Fair enough.  As also commented, it's not a legal thing to do but if you're sure it is what you want to do someone may indeed be able to suggest a similar option.

Comment: @ErikThysell Are you using one of the routines here? http://www.netlib.org/fftpack/

Comment: @roygvib I think I was using an f90 double precision version I found somewhere. I downloaded th .f version from netlib instead and put all functions in one .f file and it compiled to an.o file, although with quite a few warnings about real to integer converrsions..

Comment: @ErikThysell A workaround is to compile the library subroutines and your source files separately (rather than putting all of them into a single file) and then link the obtained *.o files (e.g., gfortran -c yourcode.f; gfortran -c yourlib.f; gfortan yourcode.o yourlib.o). But it is critically important to ensure that data passed to the library is correct even if the type mismatch occurs due to old Fortran styles. As for the warnings about real & integer conversions, they seem somewhat strange and might lead to erroneous results. So need to check the argument list rather carefully  :)

Comment: As the error message says, in this code sample you are attempting to associate a real actual argument with an (implictly typed) integer dummy argument.

Comment: I would think that the fftpack was corrected for such bugs since it is so old...???

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Comment: @VladimirF : I can see the fortran tag from my view, and I think it has always been there - or did you just add it?

Comment: Check the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I refactored FFTPACK 5.1 from FORTRAN 77 to Fortran 2008. I performed a C-language style cast without copying as follows:

```
use ISO_C_binding, only: c_f_pointer, c_loc

integer, parameter :: N = 42
complex, target    :: c(N) ! Also works for the allocatable attribute
real, pointer      :: r(:) => null()

! Pass memory address from complex array to real array
call c_f_pointer(c_loc(c), r, shape=[2*size(c)])

call procedure_expecting_real_arg(r, ....)

! Terminate association
nullify( r )
```