# Is the storage of COMPLEX in fortran guaranteed to be two REALs?

Tags: fortran, fft

Many FFT algorithms take advantage of complex numbers stored with alternating real and imaginary part in the array. By creating a COMPLEX array and passing it to a FFT routine, is it guaranteed that it can be cast to a REAL array (of twice the size) with alternating real and imaginary components?

```
    subroutine fft (data, n, isign)
      dimension data(2*n)

      do 1 i=1,2*n,2
        data(i) = ..
        data(i+1) = ..
 1    continue
    return
    end

    ...
    complex s(n)
    call fft (s, n, 1)
    ...
```

(and, btw, is dimension data(2*n) the same as saying it is a REAL?)

Comment: just addressing your last question, `dimension data` makes data real only as a result of implicit typing, which you ought to not use.  You should use `real data(2 n)` instead (that doesn't affect the rest of the discussion here though)

Comment: thanks, that clarifies it - my knowledge of fortran is rudimentary, if the only call to this subroutine is with a complex (n) as argument, why would it not be interpreted to be complex data (2*n)?  which would be a problem here... trying to figure out some code that has been in the works since the 80s.

Comment: variables never inherit type from the calling scope. It is up to you to ensure that they are consistent.  (or in this case deliberately inconsistent and relying on an assumption about the storage arrangement ).  My feeling is what this code is doing is safe, though I'll stop short of posting that as an answer as I'm not a standards expert.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160456/gfortran-complex-actual-to-real-dummy-argument/38413869#38413869

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm only writing this answer because experience has taught me that as soon as I do write this sort of answer one of the real Fortran experts hereabouts piles in to correct me.

I don't think that the current standard, nor any of its predecessors, states explicitly that a `complex` is to be implemented as two neighbouring-in-memory `reals`.  However, I think that this implementation is a necessary consequence of the standard's definitions of `equivalence` and of `common`.  I don't think I have ever encountered an implementation in which a `complex` was not implemented as a pair of `reals`.

The standard does guarantee, though that a `complex` can be converted into a pair of `reals`.  So, given some definitions:

```
complex :: z
complex, dimension(4) :: zarr
real :: r1, r2
real, dimension(8) :: rarr
```

the following will do what you might expect

```
r1 = real(z)
r2 = aimag(z)
```

Both those functions are elemental and here comes a wrinkle:

```
real(zarr)
```

returns a 4-element array of reals, as does

```
aimag(zarr)
```

while

```
[real(zarr), aimag(zarr)]
```

is an 8-element array of reals with the real parts of `zarr` followed by the complex parts.  Perhaps

```
rarr(1:8:2) = real(zarr)
rarr(2:8:2) = aimag(zarr)
```

will be OK for you.  I'm not sure of any neater way to do this though.

Alexander's not the only one able to quote the standard !  The part he quotes left me wondering about non-default complex scalars.  So I read on, and I think that para 6 of the section he points us towards is germane

> a nonpointer scalar object of any type not specified in items (1)-(5)
>   occupies a single unspecified storage unit that is different for each
>   case and each set of type parameter values, and that is different from
>   the unspecified storage units of item (4),

I don't think that this has any impact at all on any of the answers here.

Comment: Thanks all of you, libraries and applications using libraries that I have come across makes the _assumption_ that the implementation stores the complex components consecutively (alternating in an array). In which case correct behaviour is, as far as I can tell, ensured while changing between REAL (assuming alternating real and imaginary components) and COMPLEX references into the same memory (as long as they are based on the same precision).

Comment: *"However, I think that this implementation is a necessary consequence of the standard's definitions of equivalence and of common"* . I don't think so... The standard says that a complex shall occupy 2 contiguous numeric storage unit, but doesn't further describe anything. Nothing prevents a compiler to store first the imaginary part and then the real part, or store the modulus and the argument, possibly using 40bits for the modulus and 24 bits fixed point for the argument, etc... Not to say that this would be pertinent, just standard-conforming.

Answer (score 4):

To append to [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31591152/2737715) this is indeed stated in the Standard: Clause 16.5.3.2 "Storage sequence":

> 2 In a storage association context
>
> [...]
>
> (2) a nonpointer scalar object that is double precision real or
>   default complex occupies **two contiguous numeric storage units**,

emphasis mine.

As for storage association context: Clause 16.5.3.1 "General" reads

> 1 Storage sequences are used to describe relationships that exist
>   among variables, common blocks, and result variables. Storage
>   association is the association of two or more data objects that occurs
>   when two or more storage sequences share or are aligned with one or
>   more storage units.

So this occurs for `common` blocks, explicit `equivalence`, and result variables. As [Mark's said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31591152/2737715), there is no explicit statement for the general case. 
My guess is, that it is most convenient to follow this always to ensure compatibility.

Thanks to IanH to pointing this out!

Comment: This might have implications for likely implementation that practically guarantee the desired outcome, but beyond that I'm not sure this is technically relevant.  Where's the storage association context (as opposed to sequence association) in the OP's example?

Comment: @IanH This is specified in (7) in the same clause: *a nonpointer array occupies a sequence of contiguous storage sequences, one for each array element,
in array element order [...]*

Comment: But that still only applies *in a storage association context*.  What is the storage association context?  Where is the EQUIVALENCE or COMMON  statement?

Comment: @IanH Now I see your point! Storage association only occurs for common blocks, result variables, and when explicitely using `equivalence`. The missing gap here is what Mark has stated in is answer - you need to ensure compatibility with those cases... But it is never explicitly stated in the Standard! Weird ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know.

You can have storage association between a real single precision array and a complex single precision array by EQUIVALENCE, COMMON, and ENTRY statement.

But in general you cannot pass a complex array to a subroutine that expects a real array.