# Equivalence in fortran 77 (real and complex variable)

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am trying to understand Fortran 77 code but stumbled on EQUIVALENCE() statement on the code.

Here is part of the code:

```
REAL*8 DATA1(0:N-1)
COMPLEX*16 DATA2(0:N/2-1)
EQUIVALENCE(DATA1, DATA2)
...
...
CALL FFT(DATA1, N/2, -1)
```

Basically FFT subroutine is a one-dimensional complex-to-complex FFT engine. There are some permutation and matrix-vector multiplication on the subroutine.

The code calls DATA2 later in this manner:

```
K0=DATA2(0)
K1=DCONJG(DATA2(0))
```

can anyone give me clue about why EQUIVALENCE() statement is used? My assumption is DATA1 which is REAL, being changed to DATA2, which is COMPLEX variable with some changed performed on FFT subroutine. But if it is so, how about the imaginary part of DATA2? Because the FFT subroutine only contains REAL variable. And why the array size of DATA1 and DATA2 is different?

I can not find any answer in this forum which satisfy my question. Thanks for your answers. It would help me a lot.

Comment: thanks for the link, I can't find it before.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark So, let me say, if DATA1(0) contains  value of 1, DATA2(0) contains value of 1 to both real and imaginary part?

Comment: `data1(0)` and `data1(1)` are the real and imaginary parts of `data2(0)`.

Comment: @agentp thanks! It makes more sense now. :)

Comment: Yeah, the gold hammer works both ways. The drawback is that the link is now gone. I don't remeber which question it linked to.

Comment: @VladimirF It was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31590004).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`equivalence` is one of Fortran's two features for *storage-association* of entities.  (The other is `common` blocks on which topic I will remain silent here).  The `equivalence` statement declares that the entities named in its argument list share the same storage locations.  In this case `data1` and `data2` share the same memory locations.

If you have a tool for inspecting memory locations and point it at `data1` you'll see something like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|          |          |          |          |          |
| data1(0) | data1(1) | data1(2) | data1(3) | data1(4) | data1(...
|          |          |          |          |          |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Point the same tool at `data2` and you'll see something like this

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|                     |                     |                     
|        data2(0)     |        data2(1)     |        data2(....         
|   re          im    |   re          im    |   re          im    
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

but the 'truth' is rather more like

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|                     |                     |          
| data1(0)  data1(1)  | data1(2)   data1(3) | data1(4)   data1(...
|                     |                     |                     
|        data2(0)     |        data2(1)     |        data2(....         
|   re          im    |   re          im    |   re          im    
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

`data1(0)` is at the same location as the real component of `data2(0)`.  `data1(1)` is the imaginary component of `data2(0)`, and so forth.

This is one of the applications of `equivalence` which one still occasionally comes across -- being able to switch between viewing data as `complex` or as pairs of `reals`.  However, it's not confined to this kind of type conversion, there's nothing to say you can't equivalence integers and reals, or any other types.

Another use one occasionally still sees is the use of `equivalence` for remapping arrays from one rank to another.  For example, given

```
integer, dimension(3,2) :: array2
integer, dimension(6)   :: array1
```

and

```
equivalence(array1(1),array2(1,1))
```

the same elements can be treated as belonging to a rank-2 array or to a rank-1 array to suit the program's needs.

`equivalence` is generally frowned upon these days, most of what it has been used for can be done more safely with modern Fortran.  For more, you might care to look at my answer to [Is the storage of COMPLEX in fortran guaranteed to be two REALs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590004/is-the-storage-of-complex-in-fortran-guaranteed-to-be-two-reals/)

Comment: the best expllanation about sharing memory allocation which I couldn't understand before. Thanks.
Actually I need to port the fortran code to c++ so I have to fully understand the code to at least have some hints about what c++ implementations should be.