# Passing a "pointer" to imaginary part of a complex Fortran array to a BLAS routine

Tags: fortran, blas, fortran2008

I'd like to pass a "pointer" to imaginary part of a complex Fortran array to a BLAS function that operates on real numbers only. I mean a "pointer" in a C language sense, as I do not want any data copying involved.

For example, consider the following simple code (my actual code is slightly more complicated):

```
function foo(c1, c2, n) result(r)
  complex, dimension(:), intent(in) :: c1, c2
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  real :: r

  real, external :: SDOT

  r = SDOT(n, c1(1)%re, 2, c2(1)%im, 2)
end function foo
```

Unfortunately, `%re` and `%im` are specified in Fortran 2008 only. Moreover, I'm not sure the standard allows to apply complex part selector to the individual elements of array, as neither of my compilers support that.

`gfortran` complains with "Unexpected ‘%’ for nonderived-type variable".

Is there any other way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Fortran also has pointers. However, you sample does not use them. Do you really need a pointer or you just want to pass an argument?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590004/is-the-storage-of-complex-in-fortran-guaranteed-to-be-two-reals/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874982/equivalence-in-fortran-77-real-and-complex-variable

Comment: `c1(1)%re` is perfectly valid, but not an array, so I'm not sure what you mean by that part of the question.

Comment: I suppose he would like c1(:)%re in the end

Comment: @VladimirF, that's indeed my guess (or even `c1%re`).  That's quite valid too.  (For the asker:) It won't be simply contiguous though, so there may well end up being a copy anyway (just by the compiler not explicitly by the user).

Comment: @francescalus Yes, a copy is quite certain. I think the problem with `c1%re` is the lack of support in the compilers for that.

Comment: @francescalus Actually some people liked to pass just one element `c1(1)` with the hope that it passes just the address of it and no array copy is made for sure. Obviously, that will not produce the correct result here.

Comment: @VladimirF Very true.  This is certainly one situation where sequence association would scare me too much to even think about.

Comment: @francescalus, gfortran 6.2.1 (`-std=f2008`) does not understand `c1(1)%re` expression.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to first create a subroutine with an explicit shape or assumed size real argument with one rank of size 2 added:

```
function foo(c1, c2, n) result(r)
  complex, dimension(:), intent(in) :: c1, c2
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  real :: r

  real, external :: bar

  r = bar(c1, c2, n)
end function foo

function bar(c1, c2, n) result(r)
  real, dimension(2,n), intent(in) :: c1, c2
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  real :: r

  r = SDOT(n, c1(1,:), 2, c2(2,:), n)
end function
```

Keep `bar` in a different source file and with implicit interface so that the compiler does not complain. For discussion about validity of this see [Is the storage of COMPLEX in fortran guaranteed to be two REALs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590004/is-the-storage-of-complex-in-fortran-guaranteed-to-be-two-reals/)

Unfortunately, it will still create temporary copies of the arrays. Only if you used assumed shape arguments in `SDOT` and have explicit interface for that it would actually help to avoid copies.

Even if you created Fortran real pointers for the real and imaginary part, still a temporary copy would be made if you passed it to an external function.

Comment: Yes, actually it should work. I tried to avoid it because of complications with 2D complex arrays in matrix oriented BLAS routines.

Comment: @Vladimir F, thanks for the hints. I'd except `c1` and `c2` as `real c1(*), c2(*)` in `bar()`. So, we could invoke `r = SDOT(n, c1(1), 2, c2(2), n)` and avoid copying.

Answer (score 0):

As per [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40916228/1800052) of [@Vladimir F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721644/vladimir-f), I ended up with the following code.

`bar.F` file:

```
function bar(c1, c2, n) result(r)
  real, intent(in) :: c1(*), c2(*)
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  real :: r

  r = SDOT(n, c1(1), 2, c2(2), 2)
end function bar
```

`foo.F` file:

```
function foo(c1, c2, n) result(r)
  complex, dimension(:), intent(in) :: c1, c2
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  real :: r

  real, external :: bar

  r = bar(c1, c2, n)
end function foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(c1, c2, n) result(r)
  complex, dimension(:), intent(in) :: c1, c2
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  real :: r
  REAL, DIMENSION(n) :: reality, dreamy

  real, external :: SDOT
  Reality = REAL(c1)
  DReamy  = IMAG(c2)
  r = SDOT(n, Reality, 1, Dreamy, 1)
end function foo
```

As AIMAG and REAL are ELEMENTAL, you should be able to put them In the SDOT call as they be a temporary vector on the stack.