# Copying a 1D array to one dimension of 2D array with pointers

Tags: pointers, fortran

This is my code:

```
Program Pointers

Implicit none

Integer::i,j
Real, parameter, pointer, dimension(4)::P_pot=[0.50,0.49,0.47,0.47]
Real, parameter, pointer, dimension(4)::Q_pot=[0.85,0.87,0.88,0.90]
Complex,dimension(3,4)::S_pot

!Description:
!S_pot=cmplx(P_pot,Q_pot)

Do i=1,3

   S_pot(i,)=cmplx(,)

End Do

End Program Pointers
```

I want to use pointers for a associating or coping arrays (`P_pot` and `Q_pot`) element-wise into `S_pot` for all three dimension of `S_pot`.
How to do that?

[Taken from the comments]
To be precise, this is what I want to do with pointers:

```
Do concurrent(i=1:3,j=1:4) 
  S_pot(I,j)=cmplx(P_pot(j),Q_pot(j))
End Do
```

Comment: Always try to come up with a question title which describes your problem, not just the topic. See [ask] for examples. You can use [fortran] and [pointers] in the tags, no need to say the same in the title, say what is the *actual* question.

Comment: This is what I want to do with pointers:
`Do concurrent(i=1:3,j=1:4)

S_pot(I,j)=cmplx(P_pot(j),Q_pot(j))


End Do`

Comment: @Judge_Dred Do you want to copy them, or do you want them to be pointers, i.e. if `Q_pot` or `P_pot` change, so should `S_pot`?

Comment: Every single change in `P_pot` or `Q_pot` must make change in `S_pot`. I want to copy them with =>.

Comment: @Judge_Dred I edited your question and added your comment for clarification. If you don't like it, feel free to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers is not possible in this context, as complex values are usually represented by real and imaginary pairs, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590004/is-the-storage-of-complex-in-fortran-guaranteed-to-be-two-reals/31591482#31591482).

So even when using `equivalence` to map the array of complex numbers to an array of reals twice as long, you would need to interleave the real and imaginary values.

This is not possible with pointer association or equivalence. 
So the only choice you have here is to copy your values as you have proposed in the comments, e.g.:

```
S_pot = spread( cmplx(P_pot,Q_pot), 1, 3 )
```