# implicit real - complex conversion in fortran

Tags: types, fortran, polymorphism

New standards of fortran are more strict about the mismatches between the calls and the procedure definition. However, there are a lot of legacy codes where, for instance, complex array is viewed as a collection of reals. This still can be properly compiled by lowering such errors to warnings. In `gfortran` it is achieved with the `-fallow-argument-mismatch`. This provides a temporary working solution, but is unsatisfactory in long-run.

```
program polymorphic_types_wrk
  use Maux_wrk
  implicit none
  integer, parameter       :: dp = kind(1.d0), dim = 10
  real(dp)                 :: wd(2 * dim)
  complex(dp)              :: wz(dim)

  call random_number(wd)
  call copy_real_complex_nonconformant(dim, wd, wz)
  
end program polymorphic_types_wrk

module Maux_wrk

contains
    subroutine copy_real_complex_nonconformant(dim, wd, wz)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
    integer, intent(in)     :: dim
    real(dp), intent(in)    :: wd(*)
    complex(dp), intent(out):: wz(*)

    call zcopy(dim, wd, 1, wz, 1)

  end subroutine copy_real_complex_nonconformant
  
end module Maux_wrk
```

In this example, `zcopy` is [a standard BLAS subroutine](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d5/d2b/group__copy_gaca1a115319081adeb0a9b80ec37ce626.html#gaca1a115319081adeb0a9b80ec37ce626). The goal is to copy an array of reals to an array of complexes assuming the data is contiguous. According to the `gfortran` documentation a standard-conformant solution is possible:

> Using this option is strongly discouraged. It is possible to provide
> standard-conforming code which allows different types of arguments by
> using an explicit interface and TYPE(*).

So, I modified the code respectively, but it does not compile (Assumed-type argument `wd` requires an explicit interface):

```
program polymorphic_types
  use Maux
  implicit none
  integer, parameter       :: dp = kind(1.d0), dim = 10
  real(dp)                 :: wd(2 * dim)
  complex(dp)              :: wz(dim)

  call random_number(wd)
  call copy_real_complex(dim, wd, wz)
  
end program polymorphic_types

module Maux

contains
  subroutine copy_real_complex(dim, wd, wz)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
    integer, intent(in)     :: dim
    type(*), intent(in)     :: wd(..)
    complex(dp), intent(out):: wz(..)

    call zcopy(dim, wd, 1, wz, 1)

  end subroutine copy_real_complex
      
end module Maux
```

It puzzles me since all module subroutines are already having an explicit interface. What kind of interface is required?

Comment: Newer versions of Fortran are not stricter; newer versions of compilers are better at detecting violations.

Comment: The BLAS `zcopy` takes two complex arguments. You can do anything you like with making your argument passing in your own code compliant, but ultimately you'll need to pass two complex arguments to `zcopy`, not one effective real argument and one complex.

Comment: `zcopy` has no explicit interface, so you can directly call it with real arguments. Although non standard-conforming it will "just work", because all compilers follow the same implicit convention that consists in storing a complex number by the sequence real part/imaginary part. I have recently [proposed to standardize this implicit convention](https://github.com/j3-fortran/fortran_proposals/pull/325/files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard conforming way to associate a real actual argument with a complex dummy argument. That was just as true 45 years ago.

What has changed in 45 years has been the tools available to developers to provide alternatives to non-conforming argument mismatches: first generics and then polymorphism and C interoperability. Compilers have also reduced their tolerance for deliberate violations and improved their diagnostics for unintentional violations.

Assumed type (`type(*)`) dummy arguments are a Fortran 2018 form of polymorphism, particularly suited to C interoperability. This is not a form of polymorphism which allows a real actual argument to be associated with a complex dummy argument.

First, to answer about the error about a missing explicit interface. The subroutine `copy_real_complex` in the module `Maux` does indeed have an explicit interface available in the main program where it is referenced (through use association).

However, the subroutine `zcopy` referenced in the subroutine `copy_real_complex` does not have an explicit interface available in the subroutine. The compiler is complaining about *this* missing explicit interface.<sup>1</sup>

You need to pass a declared complex `wd` to `zcopy`. An assumed type variable is not a declared complex variable, even if it's a dynamic complex variable (and certainly not if its dynamic type is something completely different).

If you want to make all your argument associations compliant, then you'll need to convert (in some way) your `wd` to a complex entity. This answer is about the need of/complaints about an explicit interface, but you can find other questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36977737/3157076) about how you can do that conversion. There are ways without lying to your compiler about type matching, but you may decide that `-fallow-argument-mismatch` is just about acceptable.

The compiler documentation's comments about the use of `type(*)` allowing the writing of standard-conforming code is about how, in this case, `zcopy` could be written. It's not about how something which *calls* `zcopy` should be written.

For practical examples, see how MPI's Fortran 2008 bindings take advantage of `type(*)` and `dimension(..)`. These allow a single specific procedure such as `MPI_SEND` to take buffers of any type and rank and don't require the same characteristics in each reference.

Finally, for the case of the question, the type mismatch makes assumptions about how default real and complex are stored. The Fortran standard gives some assurance about this storage, but much less assurance about the storage of non-default real and non-default complex.

If you want to avoid `-fallow-argument-mismatch` you will need to write conforming code and that conforming code will need the actual arguments to BLAS's `zcopy` to be complex and not real. Consistently using complex entities can be one way, noting

```
call random_number(wz%Re)
call random_number(wz%Im)
```

won't require any hacks. CBLAS also provides an interface to a language which is much less fussy about type matching.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although when we look at the definition of BLAS `zcopy` there's nothing there that [requires an explicit interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31630662/3157076) when referenced, the compiler doesn't know what `zcopy` looks like. Recall that "explicit" and "implicit" interfaces [aren't properties of the procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75367793/3157076) itself, but are about what's known in the place referencing the procedure.

Instead, the compiler knows that a conforming call means that `zcopy` has a polymorphic dummy argument: the variable `wd` which is an actual argument is polymorphic, and polymorphic in a way that it may be associated only with a default argument which is polymorphic. A polymorphic dummy argument requires an explicit interface.

The reference in the subroutine `copy_real_complex_nonconformant` in the module `Maux_wrk` to `zcopy` does not lead to a similar conclusion requiring an explicit interface.

Comment: The `type(*)` is for the _provider_. In this case it's `zcopy`, and it's `zcopy` that would need to be written with assumed type (or as a generic, or other polymorphism). As a _consumer_ of `zcopy` with a declared complex dummy argument, there's nothing you can do with `type(*)`. As you see, you can have an intermediate wrapper around `zcopy` with assumed type and assumed rank, but to make that final call to `zcopy`, you need the conversion.#

Comment: See, for example, the difference between the F77 to F2003 MPI interfaces, and F2008 and F2018. `use mpi_f08` offers `type(*)` and `dimension(..)` which aren't in the previous; these allow explicit interfaces with choice arguments and enhanced compliance, checks, etc., for developing against MPI.

Comment: Inspecting carefully your link: there are no ways, there are just holes that developers have not closed yet.

Comment: I'll update my answer based on your set of comments here. But to note before then: you're never compelled to accept _any_ answer to a question you ask here. Accepting an answer signals to everyone else that you feel it answers your question to your satisfaction.