# Dealing with assumed-type, assumed-rank dummy arguments

Tags: types, fortran, polymorphism

This question is a continuation of my previous post. One question per post, therefore asking a separate question. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941421/4954079) asserts

> The compiler documentation's comments about the use of type(*)
> allowing the writing of standard-conforming code is about how, in this
> case, zcopy could be written. It's not about how something which calls
> zcopy should be written.

So how should `zcopy` be written? Can actually Fortran perform any useful operations on the assumed-type, assumed-rank dummy arguments if any operation (except `rank`)  requires to know the type (my guess)? Can one, for instance, write an implementation of `copy_something_to_complex` without calling a C-function?

```
program polymorphic_types
  use Maux
  implicit none
  integer, parameter       :: dp = kind(1.d0), dim = 10
  real(dp)                 :: wd(2 * dim)
  complex(dp)              :: wz(dim)

  call random_number(wd)
  call copy_something_to_complex(dim, wd, wz)
  
end program polymorphic_types

module Maux

contains
  subroutine copy_something_to_complex(dim, wd, wz)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
    integer, intent(in)     :: dim
    type(*), intent(in)     :: wd(..)
    complex(dp), intent(out):: wz(..)

    ! fortran code? ---> call zcopy(dim, wd, 1, wz, 1)

  end subroutine copy_something_to_complex
      
end module Maux
```

Comment: Early drafts of F2018 (where assumed rank and assumed type were introduced) essentially had this polymorphism useful _only_ in terms of C interop. Even in F2023 it's hard to find broad winning cases for `type(*)`, but much easier than in early-F2018. How much detail, evidence, or convincing are you after?