# Building libfeast eigenvalue solver with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, libfeast

I'm trying to build [libfeast](http://www.feast-solver.org/) using gfortran and without MKL (for an existing project, doing tests building it without MKL).

Build command
`make F90=gfortran MKL=no MPI=openmpi feast`

This gives me Fortran errors

```
/tmp/FEAST/4.0/src/kernel/dzfeast.f90:917:82:

  650 |      call DGEMM('T','N',fpm(23),fpm(23),N,-DONE,work,N,q,N,DZERO,Aq,M0) ! projection
      |                                                                 2                 
......
  917 |      call DGEMM('N','N',N,fpm(25),fpm(23),DONE,work(1,1),N,Aq(1,fpm(24)),M0,DZERO,workc(1,fpm(24)),N)
      |                                                                                  1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/REAL(8)).
/tmp/FEAST/4.0/src/kernel/dzfeast.f90:944:87:

  839 |            call DLACPY( 'F', fpm(23), fpm(23),Bq, M0, Bqo, fpm(23) )
      |                                                      2                                 
......
  944 |      if ((fpm(5)==1).and.(loop==0))  call DLACPY( 'F', N, fpm(25),work(1,fpm(24)) , N, workc(1,fpm(24)), N )
      |                                                                                       1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/REAL(8)).
```

By default the build uses Intel ifort, which I suppose is more permissive.

I've never used Fortran, so though I can just about read the error (I presume functions are implicitly declared in Fortran and need consistent arguments)

SO suggests a similar question [Gfortran complex actual to real dummy argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160456/gfortran-complex-actual-to-real-dummy-argument).

The best thing would be a patch to make this library buildable.

Comment: We need to see the corresponding source code and especially the declaration (or implicit types and shapes) of all entities that appear in the calls.

Comment: The usual approach to allow gfortran to compile code broken in this way is to use the compiling option `-fallow-argument-mismatch`.

Comment: @francescalus thanks, I'd just found the same thing

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts has a [recipe to build this library](https://github.com/anthonygelibert/macports-ports/blob/4bd5683e5b7cf2ed20107f270578535ec056f583/math/feast/Portfile#L27).

Based on that I was able to get something to build with

`make F90=gfortran MKL=no MPI=openmpi F90FLAGS="-fallow-argument-mismatch -O3 -I/path/to/openmpi/openmpi-4.1.4/include -ffree-line-length-none -ffixed-line-length-none" feast`